# Unable to deploy Tomcat Manager in Security-Hardened Tomcat 8 (SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: Failed to start component)

Tags: security, tomcat, deployment, tomcat8

[This is how we enable Tomcat Manager in a vanilla Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

I have a [hardened Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html) that is split into CATALINA_HOME AND CATALINA_BASE which I was unable to deploy Tomcat Manager on, without having the following error:

> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal SEVERE:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [/manager]

and

> SEVERE: The web application with context path [/manager] was not
>   deployed because it contained a deployment descriptor
>   [\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml] which may include
>   configuration necessary for the secure deployment of the application
>   but processing of deployment descriptors is prevented by the deployXML
>   setting of this host. An appropriate descriptor should be created at
>   [\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml] to deploy this
>   application.

Similar posts (to list a few [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901186/tomcat-deploying-troubles), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303407/war-deployment-exception), [3](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201411.mbox/%3C546DD489.8030306@ice-sa.com%3E), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039049/severe-containerbase-addchild-startorg-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-fa)) suggested solutions but did not help.

Comment: I'd to edit catalina.policy then copy the context.xml to `%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml` to make it work. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it was fixed:

After [Tomcat Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) is set up, copy 
`%CATALINA_BASE%\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml` to `%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml`

If you have another webapp other than manager, just replace the file name accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to add deployXML="true" to the Host element in server.xml.  [Explanation](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57152#c3).